# Tomcat Apache port 80 port 8080

Tags: apache, tomcat, centos, mod-proxy

I have a vps that runs tomcat 8.0.23 and apache httpd server.
in tomcat i have 3 projects lets call them by names below:

```
/firstpro
/secondpro
/thirdpro
```

and i have a domain name lets call it www.mydomain.com

now what i wanna do if request comes to www.mydomain.com i want to forward it to

```
my.vps.ip.address : 8080/firstpro
```

the code below is my virtualhost configuration file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.mydomain.com
    ServerAlias mydomain.com
    ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass /firstpro http://localhost:8080/firstpro
        ProxyPassReverse /firstpro http://localhost:8080/firstpro
</VirtualHost>
```

so, problem comes when i type in browser:

if i go to this url: www.mydomain.com i dont get any cookies that automatically my server generates for that session
but if i go to url: www/mydomain.com:8080/firstpro everything works fine

thanks for reading all this. and i would be glad if someone could help me to figure it out

Comment: You may want to take a look at the [Tomcat Connectors](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/), and/or the raw http responses with your browser's dev tools (or a proxy).

Comment: You may need a [ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassreversecookiedomain) since you're forwarding between your domain and localhost.

Comment: Joachim Isaksson thank you so much. I set that in my virtualhost and cookies are working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need a ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain since you're forwarding between your domain and localhost. – Joachim Isaksson 3 hours ago